# Why does Vim ignore my modeline values?

Tags: vim

I'm using a Python file with the following modeline at the end:

```
# vim: sts=4:ts=4:sw=4
```

If I start Vim with this file the modeline is ignored. How can I fix this? And BTW, I have `nocompatible` set in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: I had the same problem, modeline not working -- commenting out "set nocompatible" in ~/.vimrc fixed it.  This option isn't even required if you have a .vimrc, setting it resets other options (see: vim help compatible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tracked the problem to a local plugin, called local_vimrc.vim. The fact that modeline does not work is a side-effect of the plugin.

Comment: How did you track the problem? Is there a way to find out what's stopping this? An error log or such?

Comment: You can run `vim -u NONE` to start vim without loading the vimrc (no bundles or plugins). If the file loads properly, then you know it's either your vimrc or your bundles. you can re-add bundles one by one until the modeline breaks to track down which bundle caused the issue.

Answer (score 70):

## Here is what you check...

### Step 1

Make sure your settings are right. Do...

```
:verbose set modeline? modelines?
```

If you see **either** of these values returned, it's **not going to work**.

```
  nomodeline
  modelines=0
```

(By adding `verbose` before the `set` command, you will be told what file produced that setting. Thank you, [drew010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590191/why-does-vim-ignore-my-modeline-values/41994024#comment93103974_41994024))

What you need to see is this (where that 4 is anything greater than 0)

```
  modeline
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  modelines=4
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc
```

*Note from the comments:* If you have either `nomodeline` or `modelines=0`, you are going to need to add `set` and the corresponding setting from the previous code block. (Thank you @pilat)

### Step 2

Do you have a line with a `vim:` **that is not touching any else** within the last <modelines> lines of your document?

Seriously, that's all it takes.

These modelines all work...

```
# vim: cursorline

// vim: cursorline

; vim: cursorline

vim: cursorline

# anything here vim: cursorline

even without a valid comment vim: cursorline

literally anything as long a space separates> vim: cursorline

# vim: set cursorline: <-that colon is required if you use the word "set" and this comment after the colon does not affect it.
```

Notice that **the only way to have a comment *after*** the modeline is to use the word `set`. ***But if*** you use `set`, you **must put a colon at the end** of your settings even if you have no comment. Thank you, [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590191/why-does-vim-ignore-my-modeline-values/41994024#comment93649087_41994024)

### Step 3

And this is an important one! **Are you using the word `set`?** (as described as the "second form" in the [options doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline))  Take out the `set` or add a colon to the end.

None of these work...

```
# vim: set cursorline
       ^^^ issue: use of the word set without a trailing colon (:)

# vim:cursorline
      ^ issue: no space after the colon

#vim: cursorline
 ^ issue: no space before the word vim
```

## Step 4

Have you been awake for more than 18 hours? Before you lose your mind, get some sleep. It'll still be broken tomorrow. You'll be more likely to notice the issue when you go through this list again then.

## Update notes

This answer used to include this claim:

> **Are you using the word set?** (as described as the "second form" in the [options doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline)) Well, that doesn't work in version 8, and I don't know when it stopped working. Use the "first form".

I was wrong. It was pointed out by @Amadan and I have corrected Step 3.

Comment: I always forget step 4. Good reminder and a little humor goes a long way.

Comment: Step 3 for me. space between `#` and `vim`. reading it after traced down problem myself tho. thanks

Comment: @vigilancer yes, Step 3.3 got me years ago. This time it was Step 3.1 that got me. And that's because they **changed** the behavior.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky for how long it was changed? curious because I'm using 7.4 and 8 versions on different OSes at the same time

Comment: @vigilancer I'm not sure. I thought about bisecting versions to figure it out, but that takes time. I now have 8.0 and 7.4 and `# vim: set cursorline` doesn't work.

Comment: Helpful, in my case I also had a plugin that tries to figure out the indentation from the file contents, which interfered with the (properly applied) contents of the modeline.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I did report this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_dev/bruno$20modeline%7Csort:relevance/vim_dev/aFh3X0etB7c/zl0Vi-MuFQAJ No traction.

Comment: Everything here checked out for me, but on Mint 18/Ubuntu, there is a vim config file at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim` that had `set nomodeline` in it which prevented them from working despite all other settings.  To figure that out from within vim, run `:verbose set modeline?` and it will output something like `modeline  Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim` which is where I found and commented out the conflicting setting.  Modelines worked fine after that.

Comment: `set` works if one pays attention to the syntax of the two forms. `# vim: set cursorline` won't work, because the second (`set`) form requires a terminating colon. `# vim: set cursorline:` works.

Comment: @Amadan You are correct! I did miss that trailing `:` in the spec. I'm updating my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah no worries. It’s important because only the second form allows trailing text; i.e. you can’t do `/* vim... */` or `<!— vim... —>` with the first form. That step 4, man, gets you every time :)

Comment: @Amadan I recognized the significance of that immediately and included it in my edit. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41994024/revisions#rev7c9c43d4-19b1-48b5-a1cf-d823d95ca840

Comment: so, I have that "nomodeline" in the first step's output. Now what? The next step should be to tell to add `set modeline` to `~/.vimrc` and check if solves the issue ;-)

Comment: @pilat did "If you see either of these values returned, it's not going to work." fail you in the first step? I added a note to the bottom of Step 1 just in case. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with my modeline not working.  The answers in this thread helped me find my answer (which was adding set modeline to my ~/.vimrc)

https://superuser.com/questions/323712/modeline-not-work-in-vim

Also one thing that helped me debug this was to type :set in vim.  This will tell you the different values that are currently set.

Comment: Make sure you have both `set modeline` *and* `set modelines=N`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are saving and loading views, for example with something like the following, your modeline will not be reevaluated when you reopen a file.

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

Comment: This was my problem. Is there any way to add a follwup autocmd that will trigger the modeline execution and override the view settings?

Comment: `set viewoptions-=options` would prevent saving options in the view

Answer (score 0):

The first step is **always** look in

```
/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
```

and comment out the nomodeline line.

Kubuntu distributions consider it a security
threat.
(EG: libcal allows you to run an arbitrary program)

This is only an issue if someone off system can run vim via a webpage.  *(don't trust user input.)*

It is also possible to do a ddos attack using spell checker.  *(don't trust user input.)*

Comment: Better to add `set nomodeline` in a personal vimrc than to open a potential security hole for the root user by editing system configs which maybe be wiped during an upgrade.

Comment: This actually applies to **all** _Debian_ derivatives (Debian, *buntu family, Raspbian, RaspiOS and others), but not RH, Arch derivatives or independent lineages.

Answer (score 0):

I have had such problem with my modeline and "noexpandtab":

```
# vim: noexpandtab ft=python
```

but if I write:

```
# vim: ft=python noexpandtab
```

it works again. (Thank you guys for knowledge about :verbose set ... !)