# awscli not added to path after installation

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, pip

I installed the aws cli according to the offical Amazon directions.

```
sudo pip install awscli
```

However, `aws` is nowhere to be found in my path. The installation seems to have been successful. There are a number of files located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli`, however there are no executables named `aws`. My python version is 3.3.4, my pip version is 1.5.4, and running this command on OS X 10.9. What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you import ? did you check if the library in PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: Why did you use sudo? Was it really necessary?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

## Improving the OP's Answer

The OP answered their own question, but the exact location of the executable is more likely to be different than it is to be the same. So, let's break down WHY his solution worked so you can apply it to yourself.

### From the problem

> There are a number of files located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli`, however there are no executables named aws.

### From [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332241/117471)

> The solution was to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin` to the my PATH.

### Let's learn something

Compare those paths to find their commonality:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/awscli
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin
```

Notice that they diverge at `lib` vs. `bin`. And consider that the OP stated, "*there are no executables named aws.*" That brings us to our first learning lessons:

- Executables tend to not be in `lib` folders.
- Look for `bin` folders that share a common lineage.

In this case I would have suggested looking for `bin` folders via:

```
find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework -type d -name bin
```

But, if you are going to do that, you might as well just search for your executable via:

```
find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework -type f -perm -100 -name aws
# the `-` in `perm -100` means not an exact match of 100
# but any octal that includes 100
```

### But wait

How did OP know to look in their `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/`?

The easiest answer is also our next learning lesson:

- Ask your python where things are installed.

Here is how I do that:

```
$ python -c 'import awscli; print(awscli)'
<module 'awscli' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/__init__.pyc'>

$ python3 -c 'import awscli; print(awscli)'
<module 'awscli' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awscli/__init__.py'>
```

I have 2 Pythons and neither of them use the same paths or even path patterns as the OP.

### Apply what we've learned

```
$ find /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework -type d -name bin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin

$ find /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework -type f -perm -100 -name aws
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/aws
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/aws
```

As you can see, I have 2 `bin` folders and 2 `aws` executables. I probably want to use the Python3.6 version. However, if I'm doing local trial and error work for a remote system that uses the Python2.7 version, I'm going to want to use that. And this is exactly why I have 2 version installed.

Comment: One of the best answers I've ever found on Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Comment: @VishalDesai The way you are feeling is why I add things like Step 4 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41994024/117471 Yes, it's hard to go through a list like this when you want a quick solution. But, those only work for systems that exactly match the author's. I write answers like this AFTER I have tried every answer I could find and nothing worked. These answers get linked in my DevOps team manual because we have a LOT of non-standard systems to support. I write answers that work for **ALL of them**. Hopefully that works for **MORE of you**. Sorry it didn't work for you. Get some sleep.

Comment: Apologies for yesterday's comment. The second comment actually worked for me. I got some sleep, rejuvenated and the solution came by shortly thereafter.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky thank you for this answer, it speaks well for humanity when someone takes their valuable time to explain things in detail for the common good.

Comment: if installed with pip and --user then it may end up in `/Users/foo.bar/Library/Python/3.5/bin`

Comment: @danmux is correct, and the New MacOS security model wants you the do `--user` installs instead of `sudo` installs. And this is why `python -c 'import awscli; print(awscli)'` is so important. It will detect that path. All SO answers should explain "how to get the answer" rather than "this worked for me". Not to be critical. I realize some people don't know how to do that research. In that case, their answer may help someone else to come along and expand it to be more universal. This is a great example of that.

Comment: In my particular experience, you should not use the `find` commands precisely like above, but rather `find <path from the python hack commandline> -name aws`

Answer (score 84):

This worked for me on mac:

```
sudo -H pip install awscli --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Comment: This was the easy solution and best for not so nerdy guys who just need it to work fast.

Comment: Can anyone explain how this works? It worked without any issues

Comment: For some reason this also works with pip3 to install the AWS Python 3 version.

Comment: LEGEND Dheeraj! :)

Comment: , gracias, for context it did not work for me cause I had installed python under . `anaconda3`

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Best solution. Tried a few of the above ones but only this one worked.

Answer (score 44):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path

For Modern macos/OSX, you need to find your `~/Library/Python/$version/bin` directory and add it to your `$PATH`. This will help you locate the one where `aws` got installed.

```
$ ls -d ~/Library/Python/*/bin/aws
/Users/bbronosky/Library/Python/3.6/bin/aws
```

So based on that I added this line to my `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 28):

On ubuntu and installed with pip3 without sudo, the correct location to add to my path was `~/.local/bin`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Fyi: The answer still applies for Ubuntu 22.04!

Answer (score 11):

The solution was to add

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin
```

to the my PATH.

Comment: Or, wherever your Python resides (in my case, it was /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4)

Comment: This is a VERY "selfish" answer selection. It really does nothing for the community.

Comment: I took your answer and explained it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42984351/117471

Answer (score 9):

Can use `pip show awscli` to find the installation location.

```
$ pip show awscli
Name: awscli
Version: 1.16.94
Summary: Universal Command Line Environment for AWS.
Home-page: http://aws.amazon.com/cli/
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: s3transfer, colorama, rsa, docutils, botocore, PyYAML
Required-by:
```

Comment: Thanks, this one helped narrow it down fast :).

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded from OSX 10.7 to OSX 10.9 and afterwards, my installation of aws no longer worked.

I observed errors like this:

```
$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.5
```

The solution that the operating system upgrade had changed permissions.

Giveaway clue:

sudo pip               <--- worked

pip                    <--- failed

So I did this:

```
sudo chmod -R a+r /Library/Python/
```

and then afterwards, I'm able to use the aws commands again.

Not sure if this is something that will be helpful for others, but figured I'd throw it into the mix.

Answer (score 3):

When installing in a virtualenv: 'pip install awscli' (without sudo) worked fine on OS X; but not on CentOS release 6.6, e.g. 'which aws' found nothing. The solution:

```
chmod u+x /PATH-TO-YOUR-VIRTUALENV/bin/aws
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit the `paths` file directly if you have admin rights.

Definitely go with the top answer if you don't have admin rights, but if you do then I would highly recommend directly editing the `paths` files, located at `/etc/paths`.

Use your favorite editor and simply paste the desired path on a new line:

Sample `paths` file:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/username/Library/Python/3.6/bin #new path added here at bottom of file
```

Paste at the top or bottom or in whatever order you would like the locations searched for binaries (in the event there are binaries with duplicate names).

Using the `paths` file saves you the hassle of remembering the concatenation syntax or the potential trouble if you write an faulty export statement.

Answer (score 1):

What I typically do is copy the executable to */usr/local/bin*

```
cp $(find / -name aws) /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: In my case aws was in `/usr/bin` i copied it from there.

Answer (score 1):

`export PATH=/Users/{Computer Name}/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Windows is likely the minority here, but adding below to my PATH worked for me.  For reference, I installed the CLI via pip:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on windows 10. I had to add below to `PATH` variables

For **Python**:

```
C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
```

For **PIP**:

```
C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
```

For **awscli** to work:

```
C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

check your python version but I guessed you are using python 3.3

> export PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/3.3/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to install the aws-cli package via methods found at https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-cli/. This has worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

On some distros, if you run `pip install` (without `sudo`), the binaries are placed in '~/.local/bin', which is not typically in the user's path -- but can be added.

Using `sudo pip install` (root install) causes the packages to be put in '/usr/local/bin', which should be in the user's path. However, it includes this message on Ubuntu 22.04:

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in
> broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package
> manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead:
> https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Example commands to install and run `aws` in a Python virtual environment...

```
python3 -m venv myenv && source myenv/bin/activate
pip install awscli
aws ## use awscli
deactivate ## deactivate the virtual environment
```

Comment: As with many such tools, it may be best to run awscli inside a container.

Answer (score -1):

Simply download & MSI installer (64 Or 32 -bit)
[Install or update the AWS CLI version 2 on Windows using the MSI installer](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi)

After installation, You may get an error *"'aws'" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*

Simply check Environment variable, Variable name must be **'PATH'** and put value "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2"
Close command prompt window and reopen it. The problem will be resolved.