# Add vim modeline in markdown document

Tags: vim, markdown

I would like to know how to use vim modelines in a Markdown document. Is it possible, or does modelines only recognise certain comment markers?

I have tried using this as the first line of my file:

```
<!-- vim: set ft=markdown -->
```

I also tried all these suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590191/why-does-vim-ignore-my-modeline-values) with no luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your modeline syntax is off. Add a colon at the end, and it will work:

```
<!-- vim: set ft=markdown: -->
```

Modeline doesn't care about comment markers. There are two different modeline formats:

- `[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}`

  This form does *not* use the keyword `set`, does *not* require a final colon, and most importantly, does *not* allow random text after options (such as `-->`). This means, any paired comment markers must necessarily use the second form:
- `[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|Vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]`

  This form requires the use of `set` keyword, requires terminating options with a colon (`:`), and allows the terminating colon to be followed by random text.

Answer (score 2):

I apply some markdown related settings according to the autocmd + filetype.

In my `vimrc` I have:

```
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd FileType markdown vmap <Leader><Bslash> :EasyAlign*<Bar><Enter>
endif
```

Not sure that it's the most traditional way.