# I am looking for Vim feature that one can put a comment to editing file to apply a configuation to its own file

Tags: vim

I don't remember how the feature works. I could not search it well.

I remember it looks like this:

```sh
# many code...

# -*- Vim: set shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab -*-
```

The comment tends to put on either first or last line.

Comment: See  `:help modeline`.

Comment: Also read about modelines secure issues: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36001/vim-modeline-vulnerabilities and about [secure modelines plugin](https://github.com/ciaranm/securemodelines)

Comment: Googling this was a challenge, but it did end up here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `modeline`; the documentation can be found by `:help modeline` or on article [Modeline magic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) from Vim Tips Wiki.

Code snippet on my opening post should be fixed to:

```sh
# -*- vim: set shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab -*-

# or just
# vim: set shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
# vim: shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
```

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline , https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#modeline

Comment: I would recommend reading this important advice about modelines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41994024/2571881